# ACE Editor "end of parsing" event

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I would like a function to be called back when ACE editor ends parsing the new source code to be able, for example, to add a click event listener on every subsequent `.ace_identifier` DOM node. So far, I could not find the right ACE event to use for this and the simple following code does not do anything:

```
    editor = ace.edit $('#editor')
    editor.setReadOnly true

    // editor change event - never triggered in this case
    editor.getSession().on 'change', (e) ->
      console.log e

    // changing the language makes ACE parse the source code and generates
    // a new DOM...
    editor.getSession().setMode "ace/mode/javascript"
    // ... but a this point, $('.ace_identifier') returns a empty array
    // instead of the expected list of ace_identifiers created 
    console.log $('.ace_identifier')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event for "end of parsing", you could use `afterRender` event on `editor.renderer`, But ace uses dom as a canvas, creating nodes only for visible part of the text, and often discarding and redrawing whole thing, so adding event listeners to dom nodes inside ace editor is a bad idea.

You can add a listener to the editor instead, and use `session.getToken` to get token under the cursor.

This discussion in ace google group might be helpful https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ace-discuss/XFnf3-3gcAY/u7OIMdHkGGwJ

Comment: With `afterRender` event, I am indeed able to select the `.ace_identifier` DOMs but setting a click event handler on it does not work.

Comment: Well you can add pointer-events:auto style to it. But as i said adding event handlers to every node is an extremely bad idea, you should use editor.on("click" listener and `session.getToken` instead.

Comment: How did you know about this `pointer-events` set to none! I spent so much energy and time just because of this! I'll use the optimized way later. This is for a prototyping so far.